# CSS: Blur and invert colors for entire page

Tags: html, css, blur, document-body, css-filters

When using both webkit filters "blur" and "invert", only blur works.
And if "blur" is removed "invert" works.

Also only Chrome and Opera are responding to the code.

Is there a way to make this work for recent IE and Firefox versions?

```
body {
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: You need `svg` filter for [maximum browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20filter). This answer should help ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583937/how-can-i-make-a-css-glass-blur-effect-work-for-an-overlay/27584323#27584323

Comment: I'll write an answer with `invert` filter.

Comment: Thank you ChipChocolate!

Comment: just put them together -webkit-filter: blur(5px) invert(100%);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `svg`'s `foreignObject` element to import the entire `body`'s content into an `svg` element and then apply the `filter`s on the `foreignObject` which will apply the `filter`s on the entire `body`.

**Browser support for [`svg` filters](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20filter) vs [CSS filters](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter).**

### <kbd>[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/dPpoPp)</kbd>

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" style="position: absolute; left:0;top: 0;">
    <defs>
      <filter id="blur-and-invert">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
        <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="1" result="fbSourceGraphic" />
        <feColorMatrix in="fbSourceGraphic" values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 " />
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#blur-and-invert)">
      <!-- Here goes the content -->
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/300/sports" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</body>
```

---

If you want to apply the `filter` on an event, you could remove the `filter` attribute from the `foreignObject` element initially and apply the `filter` using JavaScript this way.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('foreignObject')[0];

body.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#blur-and-invert)')
```

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('foreignObject')[0];

body.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#blur-and-invert)')
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" style="position: absolute; left:0;top: 0;">
    <defs>
      <filter id="blur-and-invert">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
        <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="1" result="fbSourceGraphic" />
        <feColorMatrix in="fbSourceGraphic" values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 " />
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/300/sports" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple way to do this. Especially if it's just a hack. In this case I'll just show you inverting colors but I'm sure the blur effect would work as well.

Basically create a Div and place it anywhere in your code. Absolute position it and make sure it's full width and height of your browser. Set the z-index to 1000 (just make it the top layer) and then apply an invert transparency mode with a background color of white.

```
// place this anywhere in your HTML
<div class="invert"></div>

//add this css
.invert {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events:none; //disable interactivity
}
```