# Glowing blur in css

Tags: html, css, blur

How do we add blackish blur effect in css? I have a piece of text in a `div` and a background image. I want to blur only the text background.

**Image**
[image]

I want to add blur effect only behind **Mickey and Minnie**.
Here is the code :
http://jsfiddle.net/s5jyoo73/

Possible Duplicate of : [How can I make a CSS glass/blur effect work for an overlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583937/how-can-i-make-a-css-glass-blur-effect-work-for-an-overlay)

Comment: But how would you see a black blur on a black background? Or do you want to get rid of the black background color? For example: http://jsfiddle.net/s5jyoo73/1/

Comment: this might help [SO how to apply blur....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image-that-i-am-setting-with-ba)

Comment: Can you also provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: I want only the text portion background to be blurred. The portion above must remain intact. That's what I made different containers for.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have show an image for me

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583937/how-can-i-make-a-css-glass-blur-effect-work-for-an-overlay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 text-shadow.

Apply `text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;` to `<h1>` and change the backgound color of `<header>` to see the changes

Answer (score -2):

Try to add:

```
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px); 
  -moz-filter: blur(3px); 
  -o-filter: blur(3px); 
  -ms-filter: blur(3px); 
   filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Comment: Really, why are people so incredibly prefix-horny these days? [Check the browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), and find that IE and Opera never supported it at all, and FF never had it prefixed. Only `-webkit-filter` makes sense.

Comment: Uh, there is **no** such thing as `-o-filter`, `-ms-filter` and `-moz-filter`. Only `-webkit-filter` exists.

Comment: In IE 9, `-ms-filter` does exist http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx