# Blur effect on the background but only behind the overlay?

Tags: css

I want the `div` to appear like it is blurring the background image of the page. Should work when `div` position is changed. Consider window resizing.

Comment: may i know why it is downvoted? and being marked for close?

Comment: Yes. Im also working on a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a CSS glass/blur effect work for an overlay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583937/how-can-i-make-a-css-glass-blur-effect-work-for-an-overlay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a neat solution that requires no js. The technique was to use the same backgroud with specific common settings

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ho7t1a8s/)

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <div class='bgblur'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('/etc/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.bgblur {
    background: url('/etc/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(26px);
    -moz-filter: blur(26px);

    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.mydiv {

    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    // not necessary
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```