# How to blur arbitrary area on web page?

Tags: javascript, css, web, blur, css-filters

Is there any feasible solution to blur any arbitrary areas on web page (include but not limited to image, element)?

Just like this, or many blurred popovers on iOS:
[image]

Comment: Might be helpful in your search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image

Comment: You just need to get random numbers for the x and y (top, left) position of your blurred area and then apply the CSS `filter: blur()` to the element occupying  that area. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image

Comment: Blurring random/dynamic areas underlying the popup maybe not possible in CSS and HTML. But blurring the whole page may be possible, Check this (https://jsfiddle.net/jo_Geek/1t1c6kpp/), scroll to the bottom and click the button to show the alert.

Comment: @Waxi Thanks! But it's about images and elements.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The area is blurred, but not transparent. Tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/czC0b.png

Comment: You can just also apply the `opacity:` CSS property to be able to see through it. If you look at the Pen that is linked to via the link I supplied, you will see the image is blurred and semi-transparent.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the box itself is blurred, not the content it covers. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQsVm.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the svg solution [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583937/how-can-i-make-a-css-glass-blur-effect-work-for-an-overlay) or canvas solution [like here](http://codepen.io/abduzeedo/pen/eJlfj) but in the near future we will make it using just css, the webkit feature backdrop-filter works  only on safari at now. Try the snippet on safari to see how it works.

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    }

.container{
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/d2b06305-f201-4127-8eb7-7410bcc0de02/2d6c2415-2b8c-430c-87a4-c516409d8488.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center center;
    }
    
.blur{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width:200px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="blur"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtcBW.png It did work on Safari on macOS. Any solutions on Chrome & Internet Explorer?