# How to get a background frosted glass effect without using background image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to make a modal window in react with a blured backdrop. What I'm trying to achieve is to **blur the backdrop content** and **Not bluring the background image** since there's no image just the content behind the modal window.
So far I've come across these solutions [frosting glass](https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/), [frosting glass](https://medium.com/@AmJustSam/how-to-do-css-only-frosted-glass-effect-e2666bafab91) and [glass effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583937/how-can-i-make-a-css-glass-blur-effect-work-for-an-overlay) but all of them use background image to apply the blur effect but that's not what I'm looking for.

react component:

```
import React from "react";
import './index.scss';




const Modal = ({ handleClose, show, children }) => {
    return (
            <div class="modal display-block">
               <div class="modal-container">
                  <section class="modal-main">
                      <div class="row no-gutters header">
                          <div class="col">
                             <i class="fa fa-lg fa-close"></i>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row no-gutters content"></div>
                  </section>
               </div>
           </div>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

css:

```
@import 'yelStrap/_variables.scss';




.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

.modal-container {
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 250px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-container::before{
  content: '';
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  filter: blur(6px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(6px);
  -moz-filter: blur(6px);
  -o-filter: blur(6px);
    -ms-filter: blur(6px);
 }

.modal-main {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 352px;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0px;
  right: calc(10% / 2);
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: $white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 2px rgba(20, 150, 255, 0.15);
  z-index: $zindex-modal;
}

.fa-close {
  color: $water-disabled;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.display-block {
  display: block;
}

.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

when I add background image to the .modal-container::before it works but with background color it doesn't!

Any help is appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: I think if you want to blur the text then the blur has to be on the div itself: http://jsfiddle.net/ayhj9vb0/2285/ - it applies the blur to the actual element rather than what is behind it - http://jsfiddle.net/ayhj9vb0/2286/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there you go.
just see the result. 
in fact i suggesting to keep the modal next to the contents that you want to be blurred instead of keep it inside the contents.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-image {
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg-image">
asdaidnasijbadkjhvbafvjhabdf vkjhabdfvk ahjbdfkv hjbfdkv s
</div>

<div class="bg-text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam sit dolores nam tempore dolore dicta quae fugiat assumenda, obcaecati, quibusdam. Officiis autem perspiciatis pariatur, beatae possimus, nulla nobis adipisci ipsum.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
filter: blur(1px);
```

Increasing the blur px will increase the blurriness of the background.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3z0fxruk/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your consideration but the problem is that my modal window (component) is loaded inside the content of the page and if I want to blur the content the modal window gets blurred as well!